# strstr function equivalent in Dart

Tags: string, flutter, dart, flutter-web

Is there a `strstr()` function equivalent in Dart?
I have used `strstr()` in PHP and I would like to use it in Dart.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a Dart equivalent for [PHP's `strstr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) :

```dart
String strstr(String myString, String pattern, {bool before = false}) {
  var index = myString.indexOf(pattern);
  if (index < 0) return null;
  if (before) return myString.substring(0, index);
  return myString.substring(index + pattern.length);
}
```

Output :

```dart
strstr('name@example.com', '@');               // example.com
strstr('name@example.com', '@', before: true); // name

strstr('path/to/smthng', '/');                 // to/smthng
strstr('path/to/smthng', '/', before: true);   // path
```